# Doubly linked list on the free store

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, doubly-linked-list

I have been programming for about 8 months, so I am quite new to programming, and came upon ADTs, including Doubly Linked List.

I realized none of the Doubly Linked List implementations I have seen were on the free store, they were all on stack. Wouldn't having each node on the free store be more memory efficient, considering if you remove a specific node from the list you can immediately call delete on said node, rather than waiting for the whole LinkedList structure to go out of scope?

At least if I understand it correctly, simply removing the node from the list using the normal relinking process does not actually free the memory the node occupies.

I know free store is associated with the **new** keyword, and where there is new, **delete** should follow. I learnt, you shouldn't actually use raw pointers to manage memory, because if you forget to delete an item on the free store, you get a memory leak. Luckily **C++11 introduced smart pointers** which can take care of this, but the problem is, who exactly is the owner of nodes in Linked List structure on the free store?

In a very basic LinkedList, we may have this

```
struct Node
{
    int _value;
    Node * _next = nullptr;
    Node * _prev = nullptr;

    Node(int value) : _value(value) {}
};

class LinkedList
{
    Node * _head = nullptr;
    Node * _tail = nullptr;
    int _count = 0;

public:
    //ctors & dtor
    //getters & setters & other methods
};
```

where **_count** is the count of elements currently stored in the Linked List. Considering one should not use raw pointers to manage memory, it came to my mind, I should probably transfer some of the raw pointers to smart pointers from the  library introduced in C++11.

The problem is, **1)** I do not really see, who exactly should own the node that is created on the free store, ie. which of the raw pointers should I transform to smart pointers?

**2)** The other issue is, will *std::unique_ptr* be enough for this implementation? And even if I use *std::unique_ptr*, will a node be deleted once I unlink it from the list? How will the program know, the node is not used anymore?

Thank you a lot for replies.

---

**EDIT:** For reference, I am adding two methods, constructor and an Insert method of my implementation. This is what I mean by having a LinkedList on the stack. As you can see, I am not using the new anywhere in my code, yet, the Linked List works.

```
LinkedList(int value)
{
    Node newNode(value);

    _head = &newNode;
    _tail = &newNode;
    _count++;
}

void InsertAtEnd(int value)
{
    Node newNode(value);

    //tail points to nothing, list is empty
    if (_tail == nullptr)
    {
        _head = &newNode;
        _tail = &newNode;
        _count++;
    }
    //list is not empty
    else
    {
        _tail->_next = &newNode;
        _tail = &newNode;
        _count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I realized none of the Doubly Linked List implementations I have seen were on the free store, they were all on stack. ". I think you are seriously mistaken. Can you show any such implementation?

Comment: Usually a container has a small handle class that allocates the actual data from the free store. The handle class can be instantiated on the stack, in another container or from the free store.

Comment: "I learnt, you shouldn't actually use raw pointers to manage memory". You shouldn't also write your own doubly linked list class (unless it's just an exercise). There is a perfectly good one in the standard library, and if you look at the implementation, you will probably find it does use raw pointers.

Comment: @n.m. I added a little more code at the end of my post to demonstrate, what I mean by having a Linked List on the stack. Check the edit to see it.

Comment: Concerning your code that doesn't use new, it stores pointers to local objects that will cease to exist when the function exits. That code is broken.

Comment: the demonstrated 'on stax\ck' linked list compiles.  It in no other sense 'works'

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Well, I just realized there is something obviously wrong with the linking in my code, however, the object in InsertAtEnd does not seem to be removed, considering [this is the outcome in main](http://i.imgur.com/U5BU1UJ.png). You can clearly see the 15 value has been inserted into the list.

Comment: Add a destructor to your node class that clearly marks the node as invalid and you will see that it is invalid. For example, set the pointers to null and the value to 0xdeadbeef.

Comment: This code is broken. Where have you found it?

Comment: @n.m. I made it. As I said, I am new to programming. Sorry for that.

Comment: OK, so much for the idea that linked list implementations allocate on the stack. They don't.

Comment: @n.m. I already got that. Thank you for your time and replies nonetheless, mate.

Answer (score 1):

Think about implementing a smart pointer: If you follow the rule slavishly, you will need a smart pointer to implement a smart pointer. In this case, you have an exception. Similarly for your linked list, where the pointers between nodes don't represent ownership. Rather the list (`class LinkedList`) owns all nodes, while internally they are just "connected".

For integrity of all this and to implement the "A" in "ADT", these implementation details need to be hidden though. In particular, the user should never have direct access to the nodes. This also means that the list and nodes form one unit (often there is a C++ `friend` relationship) and  internally they use raw pointers (like a smart pointer does, too). Since this is protected from the outside, the exception to the rule not to use raw pointers is well-justified.

Notes:

- Implementing a linked list is a good learning experience, but please don't consider seriously using that when there is `std::list`.
- Concerning the ownership management, I'd use a `std::deque<Node>` member in LinkedList to store the nodes. Inside that container, you can maintain a list of used and unused elements even. Yes, it's a bit of cheating, but it makes ownership management safe (i.e. no memory leaks) while still giving you the learning experience of building a linked list.
- Note that you can also nest classes in C++. In this case, I'd nest the node class inside the linked list class. After all, that class shouldn't be needed outside of the linked list class, so it doesn't have to be in the same namespace either.

Comment: Another user replied that what I mean by Linked List on the stack might not exactly be it. I added a constructor and InsertAtEnd method to my post. If you check that, would you say that LinkedList is on the free store or on the stack? I thought it was on the stack, considering I don't use the keyword `new` anywhere, meaning the compiler deletes all the nodes once the LinkedList goes out of scope.

Comment: See my comment there, your code is simply broken. In general, if you have any container with variable content that is not created with an upper limit in size, it can not possibly be completely on the stack but you always have dynamic allocation there, whether it's obvious from the use of `new` or `malloc()` or hidden away.

Comment: [This is a screenshot from a debugger](http://i.imgur.com/U5BU1UJ.png), as you can see, the value has been inserted into the LinkedList, even thought inside the InsertAtEnd, newNode is created on the stack. How does that work?

Comment: The memory where the local node was is still accessible. However, if you call other functions, it will be overwritten because these function calls reuse this memory -- that's the way that the so-called stack is used for storing local variables and passing arguments and returnvalues. If you don't use the memory, a "ghost image" of the former object will remain there. BTW: Check that screenshot, you will find that the "next" pointer of the node points to the node itself, which is another side effect for you to figure out!

Comment: So the only reason the value is still accessible is only an accident and in the future I may come across undefined behaviour?

Comment: Accessing the memory where that variable was is already undefined behaviour.

Comment: I see Ulrich. Thank you very much for your responses, you have been very helpful :).